# Waterproofing a section of a soaker hose

Tags: watering, irrigation, hoses

I use soaker hoses to irrigate the garden in my backyard. But this garden is divided into two separated beds, with a few meters of distance between the two covered with pavement.

[image: Soaker hose on the pavement]

Since I only have a water connection beside one of the beds, I have to extend the soaker hose from one bed to the other over the pavement (see picture). As a result the pavement always gets wet when watering the beds, what leads to water waste, but also excessive weeds and fungi growth.

I don’t find any connection offered by the producer of the soaker hose (Gardena), to tackle this particular situation where one needs to install separate soaker hoses in discontinuous series. So I figured the best way to solve the issue would simply be to waterproof the length of soaker hose between the two beds, and keep the whole setup as is, without recourse to any additional patches or connections.

I wonder what is the best way to waterproof just that part of the hose by filling the weeping pores, without damaging the hose itself. Would a shoe waterproofing spray work? Or would it be too aggressive on the material (rubber, I assume)? I’d rather use something invisible that I can apply on the surface of the hose rather than a tape that gathers dirt and dust around the seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gardena system is pretty much compatible with their other hoses and connectors. They come in two diameters and are easy to install. I would simply cut the soaker hose at one end of the pavement and click in a piece of a solid hose in between, using the standard hose connector sets, either as a permanent setup with the (cheaper) hose repair module or (my preference) using the flexible couplers.

Your setup would then be something like:

```
Faucet-[connector]-soaker hose-[connector]-solid hose-[connector]-soaker hose-[end piece]
```

Comment: I doubted whether this would be possible, mainly because the soaker hose connector is very different from the others. It has a rather tight nozzle that sprays the water into the hose with some pressure. Is that irrelevant then? Should I use a coupler like this? https://www.bol.com/nl/p/gardena-koppeling-13-mm-19-mm-zb-verpakking/9200000010826641/

Comment: I interpreted the photo as something like [this kind of hose](https://www.amazon.de/GARDENA-Perl-Regner-Wassersparender-Schlauch-Regner-Wasserersparnis/dp/B0001E3TB2). Correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: Then you can either use the “[repair kit](https://www.gardena.com/de/produkte/bewasserung/ogs/reparator-13-mm-1-2---15-mm-5-8/967315001/)” for a permanent connection or the one you linked with [these](https://www.gardena.com/de/produkte/bewasserung/ogs/schlauchverbinder-13-mm-1-2---15-mm-5-8/967314001/) for a non-permanent solution, so that you can take out the solid part if you need the soaker hose elsewhere.

Comment: Just make sure you get the right diameter. Should be fairly easy as there are just two.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem is less mechanical but I've found effective. Pipe insulation is water proof and I inserted the soaker hose through pre-measured sections cut the length of the area's I don't need water. No, it doesn't plug up hose but the water runs out the end of those sections and can be freely slid for desired outflow. Adjust water pressure to accommodate. Pool noodles work but, as they are narrow, need to be cut down the length to insert the hose and secured shut.  Otherwise, tried and true duct tape directly on the hose should work.